# Unable to Run Jmeter in my windows system

Tags: jmeter

I am getting the below error while launching Jmeter

java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences 
WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
Server failed to start: java.rmi.server.ExportException: Listen failed on port: 0; nested exception is:
        java.io.FileNotFoundException: rmi_keystore.jks (The system cannot find the file specified)
An error occurred: Listen failed on port: 0; nested exception is:
        java.io.FileNotFoundException: rmi_keystore.jks (The system cannot find the file specified)
errorlevel=1
Press any key to continue . . .

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're trying to run JMeter in [distributed mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html), the error is about missing `rmi_keystore.jks` file which is required for secure communication between master and slaves which is default behavior since [JMeter 4.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-4)

You need to launch `create-rmi-keystore.bat` file and supply the required information:

[image]

See [Setting UP SSL](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html#setup_ssl) chapter for more details

Alternatively you can add the next line to *user.properties* file:

```
server.rmi.ssl.disable=true
```

- it needs to be done on master and all remote slaves
- JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up

This setting will disable secure communication between JMeter master and slaves and you will not have to create the keystore.

Comment: Hi Dmitri,The above solution has worked.Thanks for the solution.